# Python: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python

So I am tasked with creating a function that returns the amount of times a substring appears in a given string and the index of the substring every time it appears.

But when I run my code, I get a "I/O operation on closed file" error. Anyone know how to fix this?

```
# 1. Import the text.csv file
import csv
with open('text.csv') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')


# 2. Complete function counter. The function should return the number
of times the substring appears & their index


def counter(substring):
    substring_counter = 0
    string = csv_reader
    for substring in csv_file:
        substring_counter = substring_counter + 1
        print('Counter = ', substring_counter)
        print(string.find(substring))
# do not edit the code below
counter("TCA")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader) is local to the module, not your function. The reader object returned by csv module maintains a reference a file handle (returned by `open`). On the first iteration of the for loop, that file handle ends up going to the end, i.e., it gets exhausted but on the second iteration, you are causing csv reader object to try to read from the end of a file which causes that error.

Before or after every iteration of the loop, you can reset file pointer to beginning by doing something like this: `csv_file.seek(0)`

A better solution would be to store all the file contents into a buffer and access it repeatedly (without having to re-read file contents from file handle).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `with` (which is good), you have explicitly limited the scope of the open file, yet as the previous response pointed out, the csv reader object is used outside that scope. The reader in this case is just a wrapper for the file and does not read everything initially. You either need to read the whole file within the `with` or move the `with` inside the function and everything that references the file under it.